# sum of left leaf nodes in a binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

This solution shows me segmentation fault, though it works fine for all the trees I tried. can anyone please help me detect the error.
code:

```
    /*Structure of the node of the binary tree is as
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node* left;
        struct Node* right;
    };
    */
    // function should return the sum of all 
    // left leaf nodes
    int sum=0,i=1;
    Node* h;
    int leftLeafSum(Node* root)
    {
        if(i==1)
        {
           h=root;
           i--;
        }
        Node* temp=root;
        if((temp->left!=NULL)&&(temp->left->left==NULL)&&   (temp->left->right==NULL))
           sum+=temp->left->data;
        if(temp->left!=NULL)
           leftLeafSum(temp->left);
        if(temp->right!=NULL)
           leftLeafSum(temp->right);
        if(temp==h)
        {
           i=1;
           int s=sum;
           sum=0;
           return s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you call this function (please show the code); what's the value of `h` at this point? BTW: You should at least get a warning that not all code paths return a value.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to the question, but imo there is a better reprenstation of a binary tree: Add a flag that tells you if the current node is a leaf or not. If not, continue, otherwise just return. You can avoid a bunch of checks and possible errors with that.

Comment: - Stephen Lechner , h is a temporary node I used to store the root of the tree.

Comment: @DaOnlyOwner there is a better representation, but I want to know why this gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: @StephanLechner , h is a temporary node I used to store the root of the tree.

Comment: @StephanLechner , the main driver function is hidden from me, but it calls the function with inputs containing testcases and tree data. this function can be called for multiple test cases.

Comment: Can you provide a link?  Is there a maximum depth to the tree?  (Too big and you may get a stack overflow)

Comment: When you say "left leaf nodes" do you mean a leaf which is the left child of some node?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz , the max size of the tree is 100 .

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz heres the link : https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sum-of-left-leaf-nodes/1

Comment: It would really help if you gave example trees that give you the segfaults.

Comment: @0x499602D2 yeah, left child of a node and also being a leaf node.

Comment: @DaOnlyOwner my code gave me right answers for all the trees I checked for, but when I submit I get a segfault, unfortunately I cant see the testcases.

Comment: And if you call `leftLeafSum` with an empty tree (i.e., NULL root)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i even tried imposing that check, but it didn't help.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thanks , it worked with some small modification.

Comment: thanks everyone , the mistake was a null root case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that the initial pointer is not equal to NULL:

```
int leftLeafSum(Node* root)
{
    if (root==NULL)
        return 0;
    ...
```

When I add this in, the website accepts the submission as being correct.